# Detect if one of multiple colliders of a GameObject has a collision with another Collider of a different GameObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a character GameObject which has 2 Colliders. Now I want to detect in my the control script of the character if one of these Colliders has a collision with a Collider of another object. Currently I'm trying to detect the collision like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("ObjectTag"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision with object");
        }
    }
```

For some reason the method is only called when I remove one of the Colliders of the character. The tag of the other GameObject is the same as the one in `collision.CompareTag()`.

Does anybody know how to detect the collision of the character Colliders and the Collider of the other object?

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.unity.com/questions/188775/having-more-than-one-collider-in-a-gameobject.html

Guess you have two of the same type of colliders, try changing to one box and one sphere or something along those lines

Comment: The types are different. One is a sphere the other one is a box.